# How can I get a Hell Hound as a Summon Monster 2 option in PFS, as early as possible?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoner, pathfinder-society, unchained

[Hell Hound](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/hell-hound) is listed in the [Summon Monster II](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/#2nd-level) alternative summoning list. This creature seems nice to be used by my friend who is a True Neutral Unchained Summoner with a focus on actually summoning stuff. Hell Hound is normally on the SMIV list, listing the source as "AP29", which is, as I understand it, some Adventure Path.

How can one get access to this monster, preferably as early as possible? Does one have to play this AP to get Hell Hound as a SMII option? My friend is currently level 1. We are playing under Pathfinder Society Organized Play rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You cannot get it earlier as a summoner

AP 29 is *Mother of Flies* ([Council of Thieves #5](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8bc1?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-29-Mother-of-Flies)). And you are not required to play the adventure to benefit from that rule.

*Hell Hounds* are added to the Summon Monster II list of [Asmodean](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Asmodeus) priests (clerics and other divine casters who worship the god). The full list of spells added to their list on that book is as follows:

- Summon Monster II: Hell hound (LE)
- Summon Monster IV: Cerberai (LE)
- Summon Monster V: Bearded devil (LE)

This information was later reprinted on the [Monster Summoner's Handbook](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9ela?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Monster-Summoners-Handbook) *Player Companion* (I strongly advise you get a copy of this book), which has a list of all expanded summons for priests of certain deities:

[image]

But has restricted access, as noted on page 2:

> Clerics who are priests of one of Golarion’s major gods also benefit from having creatures added to their summon monster spells to represent the influence of their specific deity.

And again on page 30:

> Priests can use summon monster or summon nature’s ally spells to summon creatures strongly associated with their deities (and often unavailable to other spellcasters). The following creatures are available when a priest of the listed deity casts a summon monster or summon nature’s ally spell of the appropriate level, or uses a higher-level spell to summon multiple creatures from a lower-level summon monster or summon nature’s ally creature list.

As for who can become priests of Asmodeus, [Inner Sea Gods](https://paizo.com/products/btpy94wj?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Gods-Hardcover) has the following entry:

> Asmodeus's extremely hierarchical priesthood includes clerics, inquisitors, sorcerers (especially those with the infernal bloodline), conjurers, diabolists (Pathfinder Campaign Setting: Princes of Chaos, Book of the Damned, Vol. 1), fallen paladins, and cruel soldiers. Many scheming bards and vicious monks are also affiliated with his church.

As you can see, *summoners* are not part of Asmodean church, nor they get divine powers from worshipping Asmodeus. As such, they cannot gain the benefits of being a "priest", which includes several things on top of being able to summon hell hounds sooner.

However, as [noted by one of the PFS Global Coordinators](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qyfp?inner-sea-gods-what-is-diety-specific#6), a summoner could qualify for *traits* (like [Contract Master](http://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Contract%20Master)) and *feats* (like [Devilish Pride](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Devilish%20Pride)) restricted to **worshippers a specific deity** if they note that down on your character sheet, and meet the necessary requirements. But the restricted summons are not mentioned.

Comment: Hmm... I was sure I had seen a rule before that allowed casting [evil] spells in PFS without problems, but I don't remember where exactly. BTW, which features _exactly_  does one need to acquire to get those summoning options? Some feat? Being a part of the cult? At which levels can one play this AP? Anyway, thanks for the answer, it is useful already as it is.

Comment: I linked the rule, it has been FAQ'ed. But iv seen several cases of characters getting "killed" by abusing evil spells in PFS. Playing the AP is not required to gain access to those options, you simply have to either be a follower of asmodeus  (a divine caster who worships him) or a member of his church. But as with other APs, it starts at 1st level.

Comment: So, if you worship Asmodeus, you can summon Hell Hounds as a SMII option. Yep?

Comment: No, that is granted to his "priests", which are those I quoted from Inner Sea Gods. There are other benefits that is granted to any follower of any class, which I havent listed in this answer. But each god has a few traits and feats that can be picked by any follower, as noted on [this thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qyfp?inner-sea-gods-what-is-diety-specific#6).

Comment: @ShadowKras Since the question specifically asks about PFS rules, the large part of the answer is irrelevant and even misleading. Even if it's true that overzealous GM might mark you with an alignment infraction, it's easy to be challenged and reversed based on the FAQ. Otherwise nobody would bother with Infernal Healing in PFS.

Comment: @Draco-S infernal healing can hardly be used for evil actions. The whole thing is on the GM's hands, and the local captain/coordinators. If the spell didnt have the descriptor, I wouldnt mind not explaining that in the answer.

Comment: Either way, that is merely additional information. Summoners cannot obtain hell hounds earlier than Summon Monster IV.

Comment: Why not? Customized summon list in AP#29 is legal for play in PFS as per Additional Resources. Your quote from ISG says that the Asmodean church "includes" the list, not "consists of" meaning that there may be others. I don't see anything preventing a summoner from becoming a devout follower of Asmodeus and gaining a summon this way.

Comment: @ShadowKras You say in your answer that "casting [Evil] aligned spells could turn your character evil in PFS games". Which is incorrect and misleading, as it can not turn your character evil in PFS any more than casting a [Good] aligned spell can - it all depends on a purpose of the spell.

Comment: If you believe this answer is wrong, you can write another answer proving your point.

Comment: @Shadowkras Although I can't see the text to verify it, right in the first line of your quote from MSH, it says 'Clerics who are priests...'...so, that modification to the summon list looks like it is ONLY for clerics to me.

Answer (score -2):

Pathfinder Society (PFS) uses the [Additional Resources](https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/rpg/additional) list to specify what is and isn't allowed in the campaign beyond the core rulebook. These additions are listed out by book. The Mother of Flies entry includes this text

> Other: customized summon list on page 67

This seems to indicate that the rules for including a Hellhound on some Summon Monster lists are allowed. Note that to be able to use those rules in a Pathfinder Society game session, you actually need to have an owned copy of the rules on hand (i.e. a pdf or hardcopy of the Adventure Path volume, in this case).

Sadly, I don't currently have access to the adventure path book, and cannot verify exactly what this article allows, or to who. If the text quoted elsewhere is accurate, though, it is only Clerics who worship Asmodeus who can use this option. This would mean the earliest you could have access to this option would be as a 3rd level Cleric of Asmodeus. Summoners would not be able to access this option.